# thumbnail first image should not be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I kept the first thumbnail image to be selected, but I dont need the first thumbnail image to be selected. Initially i need to show the thumbnail images without any selected item, once I click on any thumbnail then the larger image should be open this is what I tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/60/

Comment: @Aby: Thanks Aby. I need to append image and video, will u help me out in that

Comment: sure.  What do you want to do ? and where's the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editted the code:
This wont select the first image as well as wont display the large image.  Once you click on thumbnail.  It will open the large image.

Updated URL :

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/69/

Comment: I have an small issue after the styling had done

Comment: What issue ?
I think you are able to see the large image and the unselected thumbnail..

Comment: Yes Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/66/, Here in the first iteration I am able to show the images, but as I close the Larger image once and again if I click on the thumbnail then it displaying the larger image to be an empty

Comment: have you understand the issue

Comment: @uui11 : updated the code once again.  Please check

Comment: I am trying to combine the div videos into my thumbs div.

SO these videos should append into the thumbnail gallery.

After the all images, the videos should be appended into the thumbnail gallery. As it is the next and prev functionality of the thumbnail gallery should be use for videos too.

Here is the demo what I tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/70/

I need a help.